# Non-ideal inductor equivalent circuit

Tags: ltspice

I'm simulating a non-ideal inductor. For this, I use the equivalent circuit implemented in LTspice which models the parasitic components (Rp, Cp and Rs).

[image]

I tried to calculate from the data sheet the parameter of the SRR6028-102Y inductor (model available on LTspice).

The SRR6028-102Y inductor model LTspice is characterized by

- L0 = 1 mH
- Peak current = 0.17 A
- Rdc = 4.5 Ω
- Rp = 1.50139e+007 Ω
- Cp = 0 F

[image]

I used the following datasheet - https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/54/srr6028-1391281.pdf and the formulas in this document - http://www.intusoft.com/articles/inductor.pdf to determine the Rp.

Q = Rp/(2*π*f0*L0) where f0 = resonance frequency.

So, Rp = Q*2*π*f0*L0

Rp = 32*2*π*7e6*1e-3 = 1407433.509 Ω, which is 10 times less than the 1.5e7 Ω of the LTspice model.

Do you know where this difference between the LTspice model and my calculations comes from?

Comment: Not obviously. However, Q is cited as 'reference' and SRF is cited as 'typical' which means your mileage may vary from part-to-part. Inductance can vary +/- 30% as well. This model may have been provided by Bourns with data from actual characterization of a physical part.

Comment: A parallel capacitance of **0 pf**?....that's unrealistic, especially if your inductor finds itself in a high-impedance situation. Most 1mH inductors you find now have some kind of ferrite cores, which requires some care in modelling its added losses. Always be aware that SPICE models make compromises.

Answer (score 1):

> *Do you know where this difference between the LTspice model and my
> calculations come from?*

You \$\color{red}{\text{cannot}}\$ assume that Q is totally determined by \$R_P\$ - the factors for determining Q are the series resistance and the parallel resistance.

You should also be using the test frequency of 252 kHz - that is how Q would have been measured. If you reversed this process using the equivalent series formula for Q factor you would get: -

$$Q = \dfrac{2\pi F L}{R}$$

Where R is the effective series value of both parallel and series resistors. The numbers come out at this: -

$$R = \dfrac{2\pi\times \text{ 252 kHz x 1000 uH}}{Q} = \text{49.5 ohms}$$

So, subtract the DC resistance from this and convert from series to parallel resistance at 252 kHz and see what the number for \$R_P\$. That's my advice. If I remember correctly, the formula is: -

$$R_P = R_S\cdot(1+Q^2)$$

Don't use SRF (self resonant frequency) as a means for calculating this.

Comment: I somewhat agree with Andy.. Q's are different and both depend on the test frequency and not necessarily the SRF or the PRF

Answer (score 0):

Here's my guess.  In the Intusoft paper, they are using the Rp to model core loss:

"The magnetic loss can be modelled reasonably well as a parallel resistor (Rp) across the existing model."

That's actually a terrible way of modelling the magnetic losses in many applications, and LTSpice has a completely different way of taking core loss into account with its non-linear inductor models or with more complex equivalent circuits.

So the LT model's parallel resistance is probably there more for numerical convergence help in the simulator and/or insulation leakage rather than to model losses.

From [LTWIKI:](http://ltwiki.org/LTspiceHelp/LTspiceHelp/L_Inductor.htm)

"By default, LTspice will supply losses to inductors to aid SMPS transient analysis. For SMPS, these losses are of usually of no consequence, but may be turned off if desired. On the "Tools=> Control Panel=>Hacks!" page, uncheck "Supply a min. inductor damping if no Rpar is given."

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a pretty sloppy model as they left out the parallel capacitance which is what you use the SRF for. Bourns' official values (to idiotic numbers of decimal places) are as shown below:

L = 1mH

Rser = 4.5 ohm

Rpar = 15013888.19 ohm

Cpar = 3.373953848 pF

But you can't derive those numbers from the datasheet SRF, you get a number for Cp that is many times too small compared to the Bourns model.

Comment: I agree, it is always suspicious of rookie errors when excessive sig. figs. are displayed.  LTSpice seems at fault perhaps in parsing Bourns datasheet with no Cp.  manually edit the result or   Choose the Wurth Electronik parts instead.